# Dropdown & checkbox filters are not populating from dynamically generated html table sourced from local MySQL database

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, bootstrap-5

[Screenshot of webpage is attached]

I cant figure out why the dropdown or checkbox filters are not populating from my html table for the chart I'm using.

I'm using bootstrap & vanilla javascript to create an interactive chart based on data from an html table that is sourced from my local MySQL database. I'm trying use checkbox filters and dropdown menu filters to filter the data from the html table. I'm trying to get the filters to auto populate based on column 2 & column 10 on my table, however I can't get the data to populate.[Here's the webpage as of now

```js
// Global variable for the chart
let myChart;

// Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Initialize the chart
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [], // Initialize with empty labels
            datasets: [] // Initialize with empty datasets
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'category'
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Populate location filters as checkboxes
    populateLocationFilters();

    // Add event listener for the update chart button
    document.getElementById('updateChartButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        updateChartWithFilters();
    });
});

// Function to populate location filters as checkboxes
function populateLocationFilters() {
    const table = document.getElementById('freightTable');
    const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
    const rows = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
    const locationFilterContainer = document.getElementById('locationFilterContainer');
    const uniqueLocations = new Set();

    rows.forEach((row) => {
        const location = row.cells[2].textContent.trim();
        uniqueLocations.add(location);
    });

    locationFilterContainer.innerHTML = '';

    uniqueLocations.forEach((location) => {
        if (location) {
            const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
            checkbox.value = location;
            checkbox.id = `location-${location}`;
            checkbox.className = 'location-filter-checkbox';

            const label = document.createElement('label');
            label.htmlFor = `location-${location}`;
            label.textContent = location;

            const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.className = 'form-check';
            wrapper.appendChild(checkbox);
            wrapper.appendChild(label);

            locationFilterContainer.appendChild(wrapper);
        }
    });
}

// Function to update the chart data based on filters
function updateChartWithFilters() {
    const startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value);
    const endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value);
    const checkedLocations = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.location-filter-checkbox:checked')).map(checkbox => checkbox.value);
    const productFilter = document.getElementById('productFilter').value;

    const dateLabels = new Set();
    const dateToDataMap = {};

    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#freightTable tbody tr');
    rows.forEach(row => {
        const dateText = row.cells[9].textContent;
        const date = new Date(dateText);
        const location = row.cells[2].textContent;
        const product = row.cells[13].textContent;
        const dataValue = parseInt(row.cells[13].textContent);

        if ((checkedLocations.length === 0 || checkedLocations.includes(location)) &&
            (productFilter === 'All' || product === productFilter) &&
            (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)) {
            dateLabels.add(dateText);
            if (!dateToDataMap[dateText]) {
                dateToDataMap[dateText] = dataValue;
            } else {
                dateToDataMap[dateText] += dataValue;
            }
        }
    });

    const sortedLabels = Array.from(dateLabels).sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
    const datasetData = sortedLabels.map(label => dateToDataMap[label] || 0);

    myChart.data = {
        labels: sortedLabels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Data',
            data: datasetData,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    };
    myChart.update();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Freight Orders</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.70/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.70/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script6.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="startDate" class="form-control">
            <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="endDate" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Location Filters:</label>
            <div id="locationFilterContainer" class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                <!-- Checkboxes will be populated here -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="selectAll" class="btn btn-primary">Select All</button>
            <button id="selectNone" class="btn btn-secondary">Select None</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productFilter">Product:</label>
            <select id="productFilter" class="form-control">
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <!-- Add options for different products -->
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="updateChartButton" class="btn btn-success">Apply Filters</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="toggleNcbButton" class="btn btn-info">NCB</button>
            <button id="toggleClsButton" class="btn btn-info">CLS</button>
            <button id="togglePftButton" class="btn btn-info">PFT</button>
            <button id="toggleKomButton" class="btn btn-info">KOM</button>
        </div>

        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

        <h1 class="mt-5">Freight Orders</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="freightTable">
            <thead>
                <!-- Column headers will be inserted here -->
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Data rows will be inserted here -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="labelv3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frfE1.png)

I've tried running this through GPT 3.5, GPT 4, and Grimoire and I've had no luck with all of their suggestions. They say it's probable that the table is loading after the filters are, which would cause the filters to not populate. I've tried using the DOMContentLoaded function, and using the $.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:3001/getData' and the .trim() method as well but no luck.

The strange thing is, when select the date range to filter my data to reflect on the chart, it works. When I use the filters on the datasets built into the table they work too.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how the table contents is "inserted" from your database. If the table is *generated* with the page as for instance in a php generated page, the location filter checkboxes *are* generated OK by your js code, as you can see from this [codesandbox preview page](https://cgxsvf.csb.app/). If you don't get them, it means the table is created after the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired.